# Merge list elements from a specific identifier to another and elements in between the identifiers to be separated by ','

Tags: python

Given :

```
lst = ['asd','asd','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd','qwe','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd']
```

For every element that starts with 'if(' till the first element that ends with '>', merge all elements in between these two and separate the elements that where in between with ','

Example of result:

```
result=['asd','asd','if(asd):<asd,asd,dsa>','asd','qwe','if(asd):<asd,asd,dsa>','asd']
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do sth like this:

```
lst = ['asd','asd','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd','qwe','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd']
result = []

i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    if lst[i][:3] != 'if(':
        result.append(lst[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        tmp = lst[i]
        i += 1
        while(lst[i][-1] != '>'):
            tmp += lst[i] + ','
            i += 1
        result.append((tmp + lst[i]))
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, stuff like this is most straightforward to accomplish using a finite state machine, or something resembling it. Here, we can use a variable `state` as a register. If we're currently inside of an `if`, it holds the next string to be outputted; otherwise, it's `None`. We can check whether `state is not None` to determine what to do with the next element, and we can then change the state based on the properties of that element.

```
state = None
lst = ['asd','asd','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd','qwe','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd']
result = []
for elem in lst:
  if state is not None:
    state += elem
    if elem.endswith('>'):
      result.append(state)
      state = None
  else:
    if elem.startswith('if('):
      state = elem
    else:
      result.append(elem)

print(result)
# ['asd', 'asd', 'if(asd):<asdasddsa>', 'asd', 'qwe', 'if(asd):<asdasddsa>', 'asd']
```

In case of a more complex parse tree, you might want to put the 'register' in its own variable, instead of in `state` as I have here; and, accordingly, make `state` an enumerable of some sort.

---

The other relatively straightforward way to solve this problem is what Gribek has answered, which uses an iterating `while` loop rather than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use two nested `for` loops using a shared iterator over the list:

```
def group(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    for a in it:
        block = [a]
        if a.startswith("if("):
            for b in it:
                block.append(b)
                if b.endswith(">"):
                    break
        yield block[0] + ','.join(block[1:])
```

Example:

```
lst = ['asd','asd','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd','qwe','if(asd):','<asd','asd','dsa>','asd']
print(list(group(lst)))
# ['asd', 'asd', 'if(asd):<asd,asd,dsa>', 'asd', 'qwe', 'if(asd):<asd,asd,dsa>', 'asd']
```